# adb cannot see device properly

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

Samsung galaxy tab 7.0
Ubuntu 11.04
udev rules are ok.
debugging on device enabled.

Problem: command "adb devices" prints device serial ID as "???????????" (lot of question signs) and device status "offline", which sometimes becomes "device". 
Anyway, running android project from eclise is impossibru because it sees device as "??????????". 
Sometimes all becomes OK after rebooting, but now it completely broken and rebooting doesn't help.

I have no idea how to solve this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the bad cable.

Comment: I have run into this issue several times on my Windows machine. It could either be a bad cable or a bad port on the device. I have three cables that intermittently do not work that I have to switch between.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

Become root first using `sudo -s` then edit new file using `gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` write a line inside `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"` the vendor id i have used here is for G1 you have to use Samsung galaxy tab 7.0 vendor id. Restart `adb`.

Comment: you still have permission problem?

Comment: There is no permission problem. There is word "device" after "??????????" or word "offline" after "??????????". But while rebooting, it detects serial number of device properly. After rebooting there is only "??????????   device" or "??????????   offline" string.